# How to filter out attributes that have matching values?

Tags: mysql, sql, xquery

I'm trying to find the titles of Books that share the same Publisher Code as well as the same Price with an XQuery.

I've already tried creating 2 book variables that will compare against each other and then print out the resulting titles, but it's not printing out correctly so something has to be wrong with the logic. I'm new to XQuery and I'm trying to basically convert a SQL Query to an XQuery

SQL Query:

```
SELECT Bk1.title as T1
     , Bk2.title as T2 
  from book Bk1 
  join book Bk2 
    on Bk1.publishercode = Bk2.publishercode 
   and Bk1.bookCode < Bk2.bookCode 
   and Bk1.Price = Bk2.Price
```

XQuery:

```
<results>
{
let $book1 := doc("C:\basex\henry\Book.xml")/dataroot/Book
let $book2 := doc("C:\basex\henry\Book.xml")/dataroot/Book
for $b in ($book1,$book2)
where $book1/PublisherCode = $book2/PublisherCode and $book1/Price = $book2/Price
return
<pair>
{data($b/Title)}
</pair>
}
</results>
```

This should print out something like

MatchingBook1 - MatchingBook2

MatchingBook3 - MatchingBook4

MatchingBook5 - MatchingBook6

Each line should be a result of a pair of books that match in both price and publisher codes.

My code just prints out every Book title in the XML File, so it isn't doing any sort of comparing of price of publisher code.

Comment: Could you share the 'book.xml' file, So I test your XQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write:

```
for $b in ($book1,$book2)
```

That combines the values of each of those sequences into a single sequence and iterates over each item, bound to `$b`. So this has `$b` iterating over each value twice, once for the first sequence and again for the second.

And in XQuery, equality comparisons of sequences return true when any value on the left side of the comparison matches any value on the right side. So the `where` clause comparisons between sequence variables `$book1` and `$book2` are always returning true.

You want pairs for every combination of values, so you need to bind a variable, one for each sequence, in the iteration:

```
for $b1 in $book1, $b2 in $book2
```

Then using those bound variables, which will each be a single item instead of a sequence, apply the `where` constraint:

```
where $b1/PublisherCode = $b2/PublisherCode and $b1/Price = $b2/Price
```